# SQL Server 2012 machine unavailable for 30min a day

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, tfs

Monitoring a virtualized server with SQL Server 2012 installed, I note that the server is unavailable for about 30 min every day (but at different time). The SO is Windows Server 2012.

The content of SQLServer are only Sharepoint Server databases and TFS databases, and both Sharepoint and TFS are installed in another machine.

Databases are not very big (max. 7GB).

I've reviewed EventViewer logs and SQLServer logs and I found nothing.

Is there any other log I could review?
Any ideas of where I can have a look?

Comment: Are you using VMM to monitor?

Comment: Did you find out what might have happened? If you are using zabbix, is zabbix able to tell you if the server was off the network for that 30mins

Answer (score 0):

On Sql Server, in Object Explorer, expand a server, `expand Management`, and then `expand SQL Server Logs.`

Right-click a log and `click View SQL Server Log`.

Comment: You can also check on C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\12.0\Data\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if logs don't show problems how do you knows there a problem?
What are you monitoring? Any counter droped to zero? Zabbix issued alerts?
Any application using that database stalled for half a hour?

Anyway, keep a look in the actual server where your VMs are running.
Those VM are can be concurring for hardware (HD, CPU, Memory) and a VM can eventually stall another.